# ¿Por qué le decimos coloquialmente "pasta" al dinero?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, coloquialismos

"Pasta" es un coloquialismo para referirse al dinero. La RAE lo recoge en las acepciones 10 y 11 de la palabra.

> [**Pasta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S5QKx5t)
>
> 10. f. coloq. dinero (‖ moneda corriente).
> 11. f. coloq. dinero (‖ hacienda, fortuna).

A veces incluso se le añade el calificativo "gansa", que también está recogido en el DRAE

> [pasta gansa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S5QKx5t)
>
> 1. f. coloq. Gran cantidad de dinero. Cuesta una pasta gansa.

¿De dónde viene este significado de "pasta" para referirse al dinero o la fortuna?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antiguamente se hacía la diferencia entre el dinero propiamente tal (las monedas acuñadas) y la pasta (el metal no acuñado). Por ejemplo en este artículo de [una ley mexicana](https://books.google.cl/books?id=I6grAQAAMAAJ&dq=pasta%20dinero&pg=PA573#v=onepage&q=pasta%20dinero&f=false) de 1854:

> 2° Los administradores de los lugares de salida, á. quienes los conductores manifestarán con pureza la cantidad que **en pesos ó en pasta** llevan para dichos gastos, señalarán prudencialmente y con consideracion á que no se graven los particulares...

o en este fragmento de [un libro de historia](https://books.google.cl/books?id=eZssAAAAMAAJ&dq=pasta%20dinero&pg=PA43#v=onepage&q=pasta%20dinero&f=false) del Perú de 1858:

> (...) mandó S. E. al señor ministro de marina que pasase á bordo de la O'Higgins á tener una entrevista con lord Cochrane, y en ella ofreció éste devolver toda la **plata en pasta**, 20,000 pesos sellados, **y todo el dinero** tomado á los particulares.

o mucho más claramente en este [curso de economía](https://books.google.cl/books?id=uK2gblRWLF4C&dq=pasta%20dinero&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q=pasta%20dinero&f=false) español de 1848:

> (...) como á medida que la cantidad de la moneda se aumenta, su valor se disminuye, **el precio del dinero** , cuando la acuñacion es libre, se halla luego al nivel del **valor del metal en pasta**.

Probablemente se le dijo "pasta" al metal bruto por una metonimia, dado que al fundirlo tiene apariencia pastosa, y una vez frío pierde esa apariencia pero mantiene el nombre.

Y el hecho de que se le siga diciendo "pasta" al "dinero" es debido a otra metonimia histórica, ya que ambos servían para lo mismo. Es equivalente a decir que los *bitcoins* son una *moneda*.

Answer (score 4):

Vaya, pues resulta que la novena acepción de "pasta" es

> 9. f. Porción de oro, plata u otro metal fundido y sin labrar.

El oro y la plata fundidos crean una pasta que es la que da este nombre más coloquial al dinero.

De acuerdo a [este artículo](https://lalenguaesagrandesconocida.wordpress.com/2016/08/30/por-que-llaman-pavos-a-los-dolares-y-pasta-al-dinero/), pasta gansa" significa "gran cantidad de dinero **ganado con facilidad**". El artículo aclara que según la RAE, “ganso” significa

> 2. m. y f. Persona tarda, perezosa, descuidada. U. t. c. adj.

Por lo que

> [...] ganar una “pasta gansa” significa ganarle fácilmente el dinero a un ganso, cuyo atolondrado y descerebrado comportamiento puede hacer ganar dinero fácil a un pícaro vendedor.

Por cierto, en el mismo artículo se explica por qué en las películas se suele usar "pavos" para referirse al dinero (o para traducir ese "bucks" que se usa coloquialmente en lugar de "dólares").

> [La traducción de *bucks* por *pavos*] Tiene origen español, y viene del año 1930, aproximadamente. A un duro (5 pesetas) se le llamaba “pavo”, porque es exactamente lo que valía este animal. En América, a los dólares también se les llama “bucks” (ciervos), porque por el año 1700 la piel de estos animales se usaba como medio de intercambio por otras cosas de valor, como sustituto del dinero. Entonces, un director de doblaje español decidió utilizar en sus películas “pavos” como equivalente de “bucks”, y se sigue utilizando en la actualidad.

Comment: Mi hipotesis es que los metales preciosos como el oro y la plata eran extraidos utilizando mercurio lo que provocaba una aleacion pastosa