# ¿Por qué le decimos coloquialmente que “estamos sin blanca” cuando no tenemos dinero?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, coloquialismos, españa

Revisando [¿Por qué le decimos coloquialmente “pasta” al dinero?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/25671/5481), donde vimos que

> Antiguamente se hacía la diferencia entre el dinero propiamente tal (las monedas acuñadas) y la pasta (el metal no acuñado)

Me ha venido a la cabeza la locución adverbial ["no tener alguien blanca"](https://dle.rae.es/?id=5eNsBBo) que significa, de acuerdo al DRAE "No tener dinero".

Supongo que dicha aleación de metal para acuñar monedas tendría un color metálico (dorado o plateado) antes que blancuzco, por mucho que brillase. De hecho "[metálico](https://dle.rae.es/?id=P5EvCf8)" (o "dinero en metálico") se usa tanto para elementos de moneda que no son de papel como para decir "en efectivo" (puedes decir que tienes dinero "en metálico" aunque solo tengas un billete), cosa que tiene cierto sentido.

Sin embargo, no es tan evidente cuando hablamos de color blanco y dinero. Las monedas son metálicas y los billetes, aunque suelen ser de distintos colores según el país emisor, no suelen ser blancos.

¿De dónde viene esta locución "estar sin blanca"? ¿Cómo se relaciona el "blanco" con dinero?

Comment: La expresión aparece en el Covarrubias de 1611. "Blanca" significa "moneda menuda". Recoge también las expresiones "no haber blanca", "no valer una blanca" (valer muy poco) y "pagar blanca a blanca" (poco a poco). No da más explicaciones.

Comment: Le pongo la etiqueta "españa" porque por hispanoamérica no he oído el término

Comment: en paises como mexico no se dice asi,se dice: "no tenemos money" , " sin feria" etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El Diccionario de la Lengua actual recoge como acepción de [**blanca**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5eNsBBo)

> 22. f. Moneda de vellón, que según los tiempos tuvo diferentes valores.

El [**Diccionario de Autoridades**](http://web.frl.es/DA.html) (1726) explica el origen del nombre y da distintas equivalencias con el valor del maravedí según la época (énfasis mio):

> BLANCA. s. f. Monéda de vellón, que el P. Mariana es de sentir se llamó assi **por la blancúra del metál de que se fabricaba**. Don Diego de Covarrubias en su tratado de monédas, cap. 5. num. 8. resuelve que en tiempo del Rey Don Alonso XI. **tres blancas componían un maravedí** de los que entonces llamaban viejos. Este valór se alteró segun la mas, ò menos calidád del vellón de que se componían. Los Reyes Cathólicos mandaron labrar diez quentos de vellón en blancas el año de 1497. y que **dos de ellas valiessen un maravedí**. Lo mismo mandó (en quanto al valór) el Rey Phelipe II. año de 1566. y aunque el año de 1602. **llegó à valer cada blanca lo mismo que un maravedí** por la subída de la monéda, como dice el Licenciado Alonso Carranza en su ajustamiento de monédas, part. 2. cap. 3. Despues con la baxa volvió à valer cada maravedí dos blancas como de antes: y assi **por blanca se entiende oy comunmente la mitád de un maravedí**.

En [**elsexagenario.blogspot.com**](http://elsexagenario.blogspot.com/2011/12/curiosidades-del-siglo-xvi.html) hacen un cálculo aproximado del valor equivalente con el euro de un maravedí de los siglos XV y XVI. Sus conclusiones son:

- Año 1480: 1 maravedí = 16 euros.
- Año 1610: 1 maravedí = 0,2 euros.

Considerando ahora la equivalencia maravedí / blanca que recoge el Diccionario de Autoridades, tenemos:

- Finales del siglo XV: 2 blancas = 1 maravedí = 16 euros, por lo que **1 blanca =  8 euros**.
- Principios del siglo XVII: **1 blanca** = 1 maravedí **= 0,2 euros**.

En conclusión: la **blanca** era una ***moneda de poco valor***, llamada así ***por la blancura del color del metal de que se fabricaba***, y el no tener ni una blanca (*estar sin blanca*) es *no tener (nada) de dinero*.